# PHP Undefined Index Notice / Error

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

A page I have in my app will not display the required text so I checked my Apache error log and I found the following notice/error.

```
 PHP Notice:  Undefined index: PetManager_Model_Groomprocedures display.phtml on line 34
```

It is due to the fact that I'm trying to display a result from a query and it can't seem to obtain this item from my result array. 
The situation is I'm querying a booking table that is related to a services table (theses elements display fine) the services table is in turn related to a procedures table(this is the element that will not display).

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong i.e. my Query or my display code and how can I get this to work.

Query Code from my Display Action

```
     if ($input->isValid()) {
         $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('PetManager_Model_Kennelbooking k')
            ->leftJoin('k.PetManager_Model_Kennelservices s')
            ->leftJoin('s.PetManager_Model_Groomprocedures g')
            ->leftJoin('k.PetManager_Model_Clients c')
            ->leftJoin('k.PetManager_Model_Kennels l')
            ->where('k.kennelbookingID = ?', $input->id);
            if('k.groomingIncluded'==1)
            {$q->addWhere('s.groomingGiven=g.groomProceduresID');
            }

  $result = $q->fetchArray();
  if (count($result) == 1) {
    $this -> view -> booking = $result[0];
```

The display code from my phtml file

```
   <td class="key">Grooming Procedure </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <?php if($this->booking['PetManager_Model_Kennelservices']['groomingGiven']==NULL)
    echo '<td>'.'There is no grooming procedure associated for this booking'.'</td>';
    else echo '<td>'.$this->escape($this->booking['PetManager_Model_Groomprocedures']['groomprocedure']).'</td>';
    ;?>
 </tr>
```

Many thanks in advance,

Graham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see the index `PetManager_Model_Groomprocedures` is not defined in the `booking`-variable.

To see which keys are available do the following in your controller to get a debug output.

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($result[0]);echo '</pre>';exit;
```

You will see which keys are available in this array. I guess you are not selecting the wanted row explicitly. You will modify your query this way, that you also do select the wanted row.

Comment: Thanks for your reply my BB is down so sorry for the delay in getting back to you. I've sorted this by changing the display.phtml code to else echo '<td>'.$this->escape($this->booking ['PetManager_Model_Kennelservices']['PetManager_Model_Groomprocedures']['groomprocedure']).'</td>';